# First-child full-width in Flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

How can I set the first-child of flexbox in full-width and all of the other childs set to `flex:1`(for split space)?

Like this:

[image]

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You can set the `:first-child` to a width of `100%`, and the rest of the childs `:not(:first-child)` to `flex: 1`.

To put them on multiple lines, use `flex-wrap: wrap` on the container:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: #e2eaf4;
  padding: 10px;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "Open Sans", Arial;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  background: #3794fe;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 12px;
}

.child:first-child {
  width: 100%;
}

.child:not(:first-child) {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
  <div class="child">Child</div>
</div>
```

Comment: impeccable solution

Answer (score 22):

Add `width: 100%;` for your first item. And `flex: 1;` for others.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex-item:not(:first-child) {
  flex: 1;
}

.flex-item:nth-child(1) {
  width: 100%;
}

/* Styles just for demo */
.flex-item {
  background-color: #3794fe;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="flex-item">
    Child
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    Child
  </div>
  <div class="flex-item">
    Child
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 11):

Another solution which utilises the `flex-basis` option (the third value when using this format `flex: 1 1 100%`).

[MDN link for flex-basis](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis)

```css
.flexContainer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item:first-child {
  flex: 1 1 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.item {
  flex: 1 1 40%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexContainer">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this solution simple. Just set desired child item height.

```
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', gap:'32px'}}>
      <div style={{ flex: '0 0 100%' }}>Some content</div>
      <div style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>Some content</div>
      <div style={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>Some content</div>
    </div>
```