# How reference an svg class in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I have a webpage that shows three levels of nested svgs generated via D3.  I'm trying to change the middle set of nested svgs into a flexbox so that innermost set of svgs will be spaced to the vertical line representing the outermost flexbox, then move down if they need more space.  My problem is that I am unable to make changes to the middle containers on the css page.  I believe I have the [right syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_class.asp)  but cannot even do a simple thing like change the background-color of the svgs classed as "second."  This brings me no changes, for example:

```
.second {
  background-color: black;
}
```

The css works on the "container" class.  I thought the difference might be because it is a div, rather than a svg, and as a result I changed all my svgs to divs - but that had no impact.

I am able to change the background-color if I do the following:

```
svg {
  background-color: black;
}
```

This isn't what I want, exactly (I don't want to select the other svgs on the page), but I wanted to test to see if flexbox could work:

```
svg {
  display: flex;
  padding: 60px;
  flex: 1 1 1;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
```

Oddly enough, it didn't work as I expected. That is, the innermost svgs were still piled up on top of one another.

Here's my code - thanks in advance,

```js
var doc = `Manual Category Function1 Function2 MaxRetentionRounded
DOG "General Furry, Program and Subject Files" Average Quantity and Planning Jack 5
TR Senate Committee on animal Standards Bowl and Plate Design Jack 5
TR Published Canine Bowl and Plate Design Jack 1
TR Canine case files Bowl and Plate Design Jack 1
DOG Canine Files  Avoiding Neck Strain Jack 6
DOG Canine Files  Drooling Jack 6
DOG Canine Files  Drooling Jack 7
DG ADVERTISING At home Jack 7
DG PROMOTIONS At home Jack 100
DG3 Publications At homeio Jack 5
TR Public and Information Services At homeio Jack 5
TR Petting Services Getting special treats Jack 1
TR Petting Services Getting special treats Jack 1
TR Petting Services Getting special treats Jack 5
TR Petting Services Getting special pats Snack 5
TR Petting Services Getting special pats Snack 1
TR Petting Services Getting special pats Snack 1
DG DEVELOPMENT Optimal time of day - walking Snack 6
DG INCOME AND REVENUE Optimal time of day - walking Snack 6
TR Fundraising Optimal time of day - walking Snack 7
TR Fundraising Optimal time of day Snack 7
DG DEVELOPMENT Optimal time of day Snack 1
DG INCOME AND REVENUE Optimal time of day Snack 5
TR Wishbone Protective Measures Snack 5
TR Wishbone Protective Measures Pack 1
DG Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Pack 1
DOG Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Pack 8
TR Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Pack 8
`;
const data = d3.tsvParse(doc, function(d) {
  return {
    Manual: d.Manual,
    Category: d.Category,
    Function1: d.Function1,
    Function2: d.Function2,
    MaxRetentionRounded: d.MaxRetentionRounded
  };
});

var legendText = (["TR", "DG", "DOG", "DG3"])

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .domain(legendText)
  .range(["#f7f7f7", "#cccccc", "#404040", "#c627c7"]);


var nest = d3.nest()
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.Function2;
  })
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.Function1;
  })
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.Category;
  })
  .entries(data);



var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0)

var height = 80,
  width = 150;

data.sort(function(a, b) {
  return b.MaxRetentionRounded - a.MaxRetentionRounded;
});


var divs = d3.select(".container")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(nest)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "innerdiv");

divs.append("p")
  .html(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  });

var svgs = divs.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('svg')
  // .attr("width", "auto")
  .attr("height", height + 20)


svgs.append("text")
  .attr('class', 'label')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 15)
  .style("font-size", "16px")
  .style("font-weight", "bold")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'start')



var svgs2 = svgs.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('svg')
  .style("width", 200)
  .attr("class", "second")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(" + i * 00 + ",0)";
  });
// .attr("height", height + 20);

svgs2.append("text")
  .attr('class', 'label')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 80)
  .style("font-size", "12px")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'start')

svgs2.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .filter(function(d, i) {
    const x = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
    return x.key == d.Category ? 1 : 0;
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d.MaxRetentionRounded * 5;
  })
  .attr("transform", "translate(2,20)")
  .attr("width", "25")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * 30;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d, i) {
    return (height - 40) - (d.MaxRetentionRounded * 5);
  })
  .attr("stroke", function(d, i) {
    return d.ModifiedRetention === "TBD" ? "blue" : "black"
  })

  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.Manual)
  });
```

```css
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 60px;
  flex: 1 1 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.innerdiv {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

.innerdiv+.innerdiv {
  padding-left: 16px;
  border-left: 2px solid lightgray;
}

.legend {
  position: fixed;
  font-family: "Century Gothic";
}

/* div {width: auto; height: auto; } */

div.second {
  display: flex;
  padding: 60px;
  flex: 1 1 1;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* svgs2 {width: auto; height: auto; background-color:#353839;}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Mapping Dog Care Manuals</title>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <div class="container"></div>
  </head>


</html>
```

UPDATE: Managed to add a new flexbox nested inside the old flexbox, by changing the svg2 to a div.  The only problem now is that the text appended to div2 is now being treated as a child of the flexbox, which is pushing the svg to the right.  (The problem only becomes apparent when the webpage is fullsize)

```js
var doc = `Manual Category Function1 Function2 MaxRetentionRounded
DOG "General Furry, Program and Subject Files" Average Quantity and Planning Jack 5
TR Senate Committee on animal Standards Bowl and Plate and Plate Design Jack 5
TR Published Canine Bowl and Plate Design Jack 1
TR Canine case files Bowl and Plate Design Jack 1
DOG Canine Files  Avoiding Neck Strain Jack 6
DOG Canine Files  Drooling Jack 6
DOG Canine Files  Drooling Jack 7
DG ADVERTISING At home Jack 7
DG PROMOTIONS At home Jack 100
DG3 Publications At homeio Jack 5
TR Public and Information Services At homeio Jack 5
TR Petting Services Getting special treats Jack 1
TR Petting Services Getting special treats Jack 1
TR Petting Services Getting special treats Jack 5
TR Petting Services Getting special pats Snack 5
TR Petting Services Getting special pats Snack 1
TR Petting Services Getting special pats Snack 1
DG DEVELOPMENT Optimal time of day - walking Snack 6
DG INCOME AND REVENUE Optimal time of day - walking Snack 6
TR Fundraising Optimal time of day - walking Snack 7
TR Fundraising Optimal time of day Snack 7
DG DEVELOPMENT Optimal time of day Snack 1
DG INCOME AND REVENUE Optimal time of day Snack 5
TR Wishbone Protective Measures Snack 5
TR Wishbone Protective Measures Pack 1
DG Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Pack 1
DOG Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Pack 8
TR Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Pack 8
`;
const data = d3.tsvParse(doc, function(d) {
  return {
    Manual: d.Manual,
    Category: d.Category,
    Function1: d.Function1,
    Function2: d.Function2,
    MaxRetentionRounded: d.MaxRetentionRounded
  };
});

      var legendText = (["TR","DG","DOG","DG3"])

      var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(legendText)
      .range(["#f7f7f7","#cccccc","#404040","#c627c7"]);


var nest = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) {
  return d.Function2;
})
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.Function1;
  })
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.Category;
  })
  .entries(data);


var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0)

var height = 80,
  width = 150;

  data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.MaxRetentionRounded - a.MaxRetentionRounded;
      });


var divs = d3.select(".container")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(nest)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "innerdiv");

divs.append("p")
  .html(function(d){
  return d.key;
  });



var divs2 = divs.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('div')
  .attr("class","first")


divs2.append("text")
  .attr('class', 'label1')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .style("font-size", "16px")
  .style("font-weight","bold")
  .attr("width","100%")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'start')

  var svgs2 = divs2.selectAll(null)
    .data(function(d) {
      return d.values;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('svg')
    .attr("class","second")
    .attr("width", function (d) {return String(d.Category).length > d.values.length ? (String(d.Category).length*30)+50 : (d.values.length*30)+20})
    .attr("height", height + 20);

  svgs2.append("text")
    .attr('class', 'label2')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 80)
    .style("font-size", "12px")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.key;
    })
    .attr('text-anchor', 'start')

svgs2.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .filter(function(d, i) {
    const x = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
    return x.key == d.Category ? 1 : 0;
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d.MaxRetentionRounded * 5;
  })
  .attr("transform","translate(2,20)")
  .attr("width", "25")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * 30;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d,i) {return (height-40)-(d.MaxRetentionRounded*5);})
  .attr("stroke",function (d,i) {return d.ModifiedRetention === "TBD"? "blue" : "black"})

  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.Manual)});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px;
  flex: 1 1 1;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;

}

.innerdiv {
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 21px;
 font-family: "Century Gothic";
 flex: 1 1 1;
}

.innerdiv + .innerdiv {
 padding-left: 0px;
  border-left: 2px solid lightgray;
  }


div.first {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: Your snippet doesn't work. Also you can use `svg.second` to select an svg with the `second` class. As a note, SVG has some different css from regular elements.

Comment: SVG has different functions, for instance `fill:` is `background-colour` — I also don't think it's possible to use flexbox as a part of the svg, anything inside `<svg>` plays by a different set of rules.
[SVG Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG)

Comment: Thanks pmkro and Andrew Robinson.  Pmkro - can't figure out why my snippet is not working when its working fine in Atom.  Will fix and repost soon.  Andrew Robinson - thanks for the information.

Comment: fixed the code - had forgotten to add a div to the html

Comment: Hi Andrew Robinson and pmkro: just wanted to say thanks for telling me the svg was not amenable to becoming a flexbox.  As a result, I changed the variable svgs2 into div2.  Once div2 was a div, I could make it to flexbox in css.  Doing this technically solved my problem - ie, all the ".second" svgs are spread across the column, with one downside: the text svg has been caught in the flexbox as well, and is no longer sitting above the second svgs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two tricks to solving this problem.  The first trick is to remember, as @Andrew Robinson points out, that the flexbox property only applies to divs, not svgs.  Therefore, the following segment of the code must be rewritten so that the element appended is a div, not an svg:

```
var svgs = divs.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('svg') **// change this to: .append('div')**
  .attr("height", height + 20)
```

Trick two: once the above changes are made, an aesthetic issue will become apparent: the div containing the text will appear on the same line as the divs containing the rectangles.  To fix this requires adding a piece of code in the css page that indicates the first child-item will be set at a width of 100%.

```
.first>*:first-child {
    width: 100%;
}
```

More information on the first-child property can be found here: [First-child full-width in Flexbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41789278/first-child-full-width-in-flexbox)

Complete code here:

```js
var doc = `Manual Category Function1 Function2 MaxRetentionRounded
DOG "General Furry, Program and Subject Files" Average Quantity and Planning Jack 5
TR Senate Committee on animal Standards Bowl and Plate and Plate Design Jack 5
TR Published Canine Bowl and Plate Design Jack 1
TR Canine case files Bowl and Plate Design Jack 1
DOG Canine Files  Avoiding Neck Strain Jack 6
DOG Canine Files  Drooling Jack 6
DOG Canine Files  Drooling Jack 7
DG ADVERTISING At home Jack 7
DG PROMOTIONS At home Jack 100
DG3 Publications At homeio Jack 5
TR Public and Information Services At homeio Jack 5
TR Petting Services Getting special treats Jack 1
TR Petting Services Getting special treats Jack 1
TR Petting Services Getting special treats Jack 5
TR Petting Services Getting special pats Snack 5
TR Petting Services Getting special pats Snack 1
TR Petting Services Getting special pats Snack 1
DG DEVELOPMENT Optimal time of day - walking Snack 6
DG INCOME AND REVENUE Optimal time of day - walking Snack 6
TR Fundraising Optimal time of day - walking Snack 7
TR Fundraising Optimal time of day Snack 7
DG DEVELOPMENT Optimal time of day Snack 1
DG INCOME AND REVENUE Optimal time of day Snack 5
TR Wishbone Protective Measures Snack 5
TR Wishbone Protective Measures Pack 1
DG Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Pack 1
DOG Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Pack 8
TR Wishbone Observant of Limps Etc Pack 8
`;
const data = d3.tsvParse(doc, function(d) {
  return {
    Manual: d.Manual,
    Category: d.Category,
    Function1: d.Function1,
    Function2: d.Function2,
    MaxRetentionRounded: d.MaxRetentionRounded
  };
});

      var legendText = (["TR","DG","DOG","DG3"])

      var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
      .domain(legendText)
      .range(["#f7f7f7","#cccccc","#404040","#c627c7"]);


var nest = d3.nest()
.key(function(d) {
  return d.Function2;
})
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.Function1;
  })
  .key(function(d) {
    return d.Category;
  })
  .entries(data);


var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0)

var height = 80,
  width = 150;

  data.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.MaxRetentionRounded - a.MaxRetentionRounded;
      });


var divs = d3.select(".container")
  .selectAll(null)
  .data(nest)
  .enter()
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "innerdiv");

divs.append("p")
  .html(function(d){
  return d.key;
  });



var divs2 = divs.selectAll(null)
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.values;
  })
  .enter()
  .append('div')
  .attr("class","first")


divs2.append("text")
  .attr('class', 'label1')
  .attr('x', 0)
  .attr('y', 0)
  .style("font-size", "16px")
  .style("font-weight","bold")
  .attr("width",600)
  .text(function(d) {
    return d.key;
  })
  .attr('text-anchor', 'start')

  var svgs2 = divs2.selectAll(null)
    .data(function(d) {
      return d.values;
    })
    .enter()
    .append('svg')
    .attr("class","second")
    .attr("width", function (d) {return String(d.Category).length > d.values.length ? (String(d.Category).length*27) : (d.values.length*30)})
    // .attr("width",200)
    .attr("height", height + 20);


  svgs2.append("text")
    .attr('class', 'label2')
    .attr('x', 0)
    .attr('y', 80)
    .style("font-size", "12px")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.key;
    })
    .attr('text-anchor', 'start')

svgs2.selectAll("rect")
  .data(data)
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("class", "bar")
  .filter(function(d, i) {
    const x = d3.select(this.parentNode).datum();
    return x.key == d.Category ? 1 : 0;
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d.MaxRetentionRounded * 5;
  })
  .attr("transform","translate(2,20)")
  .attr("width", "25")
  .attr("x", function(d, i) {
    return i * 30;
  })
  .attr("y", function(d,i) {return (height-40)-(d.MaxRetentionRounded*5);})
  .attr("stroke",function (d,i) {return d.ModifiedRetention === "TBD"? "blue" : "black"})

  .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.Manual)});
```

```css
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  padding: 3px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: lightgrey;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px;
  flex: 1 1 1;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;

}

.innerdiv {
 text-align: left;
 font-size: 21px;
 font-family: "Century Gothic";
 flex: 1 1 1;
}

.innerdiv + .innerdiv {
 padding-left: 0px;
  border-left: 2px solid lightgray;
  }


.first>*:first-child {
    width: 100%;
}
div.first {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0px;
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.13.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```